# JavaEE EJB and Groovy

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, groovy, ejb

I wanted to try Groovy and I figured using it just for the view layer for now in a new javaee project (no grails or similar). Also there was a lot of talk of groovy + javaee, but I can't find a working case that would match mine.

So I have a maven ear project, the model/controller ejb module would stay on java for now (I included groovy dependencies but it seems you have to use java for that), while the view module has full groovy support. I am using Eclipse + m2e and everything integrates and compiles fine so far. In the view module I can even make a groovy bean and it seems to work fine. The problem is I cannot find a way to inject an EJB bean into the groovy bean via @EJB annotation. Since I cannot find an example of similar setup it might be that this is not even possible.

So just to rest my curiosity, if anyone knows how I can get my groovy bean to read data from the EJB's? It needn't be via the said annotation at all, any way to do it is fine. I could make a webservice for one, but that is a bit overly complicated and redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a *slightly* old thread, but for anyone searching, i managed to successfully use Groovy in a Java EE 6 project. Both controller and EJBs injected into controllers using `@EJB`.

Here's my setup:

- Eclipse Juno 4.2.2
- Ubuntu 12.04
- Groovy 2.1.3
- JSF 2.1
- Glassfish 3.1.2

The trickiest part is that the Groovy lib needs to be copied into the `glassfish/lib`, also with my postgres jdbc driver.

I created a new Enterprise Application project in Eclipse, and created:

- connector module: interfaces and model, everything is java, but i think groovy is doable
- web module: groovy controllers
- ejb module: groovy ejbs

The controller:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
class Controller {
    @EJB ServiceLocal service

    List list() {
        service.list()
    }
}
```

The EJB:

```
@Stateless
class Service implements ServiceLocal {

    @Override
    public List<Model> list() {
        [
            [name: "A"],
            [name: "B"],
            [name: "C"]
        ]
    }
```

And the view:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{controller.list()}" var="e">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
        #{e.name}
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

And it works fine.